# Generator and auto transfer repair

Tags: electrical

I have a 100KW diesel generator with a 400amp ATS (Cummins) feeding a 400 amp service. It exercies once a week with load transfer it starts and transfers like it should however when it is time to flop back over to regular electric it does not flip back to reg power (actually everything goes dark in the house)and the generator does not stop running. I end up having to turn the generator off manually and leave it on manual and I have to manually flop over the transfer (several times before it will flop) switch back to regular electric where do I start? This issue has now happened twice over the past 6 months last time we just operated everything a few times and all seemed normal worked fine till today

Comment: I happen to be a lineman for the electrical utility I installed the generator myself

Answer (score 2):

Please contact an approved qualified service technician to troubleshoot this generator.

A 100kW generator and transfer switch for a 400A service IS ABSOLUTELY NOT a DIY situation.